# Skeletonizing an image

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing

I'm trying to skeletonize an image ([ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2xUi.png))

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2xUi.png"]
graph=  MorphologicalGraph[img]
```

Input image:

[image]

Skeleton generated:

[image]

Some of the edges (circled below for example) are missing after skeletonization.

[image]

Could someone please have a look?

EDIT: As pointed out in the comment below, there are other missing edges too.

[image]

Comment: Why do you not mention the other edges shown in [green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN0qh.png)?

Comment: @Syed  Thank you, I have added the image shared by you in EDIT.

Comment: Is the output with `SkeletonTransform` acceptable? [Output](https://imgur.com/a/WXJdPXy)

Comment: @rowsi Yes, the output is acceptable.  But when I apply `MorphologicalGraph` i.e `graph=MorphologicalGraph[skeleton]`  the same issue occurs in the resulting graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions `` to see what `MorphologicalGraph` is doing.  It calls some functions that do

```
vertices = ImageAdd[
    MorphologicalTransform[skeleton, "SkeletonEndPoints", Padding -> 0],
    MorphologicalTransform[skeleton, "SkeletonBranchPoints", Padding -> 0]
```

to find vertices.  I ran that and highlighted the `vertices`:

[image: nogoodverts]

As you can see, the function doesn't identify 'kinks' as vertices, only branches and endpoints.  Sure enough, if I open up paint and put in branches at kinks where I want vertices, it works:

[image: cyllia] yields [image: graph]

Now that's probably not an acceptable (or bountyable) solution, so I may throw together some code to do what you're looking for; `MorphologicalGraph` is too kink-tolerant.

By the way, this hodgepodge code

```
Function[g, VertexContract[g, 
  Gather[VertexList@g, 
    EuclideanDistance[GraphEmbedding[g][[#]], 
      GraphEmbedding[g][[#2]]] < 10 &]]]@
  IndexGraph@
Function[g, 
  VertexDelete[g, 
    Select[First /@ Position[VertexDegree@g, 1], 
      Abs[Last@GraphEmbedding[g][[#]] - 
        Mean[Last /@ GraphEmbedding[g]]] > 10 &]]]@
  IndexGraph@graph
```

cleans up the resulting graph a little bit by contracting close vertices (the thickness on some corners makes spurious vertices), and also deletes all degree 1 vertices (the horns I added) if they aren't too close to the vertical middle.  I get

[image: cleaned]

as an output.  If you're only interested in this one example, here's the code to make that cleaned up graph

```
Graph[Range@48, 
 UndirectedEdge @@@ 
  Partition[{1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 8, 3, 9, 5, 10, 7, 8, 7, 11, 8, 12, 
  9, 13, 9, 14, 13, 15, 14, 15, 14, 16, 15, 17, 10, 6, 17, 16, 17, 
  18, 16, 19, 6, 20, 12, 18, 18, 21, 21, 19, 19, 22, 23, 20, 20, 24,
  11, 27, 22, 28, 22, 29, 29, 31, 29, 32, 31, 33, 30, 33, 30, 34, 
  24, 35, 24, 36, 33, 37, 35, 38, 32, 37, 32, 39, 37, 40, 40, 39, 
  40, 41, 39, 42, 41, 42, 42, 43, 34, 27, 34, 43, 38, 36, 43, 44, 
  36, 25, 26, 44, 26, 25, 45, 4, 45, 5, 45, 6, 46, 4, 46, 20, 46, 
  25, 47, 2, 47, 46, 47, 11, 47, 26, 48, 11, 48, 12, 48, 22, 48, 
  30}, 2], 
VertexCoordinates -> 
  Partition[{279.5, 349.5, 183.5, 347.5, 318.5, 324.5, 152.5, 347.5, 
  75.5, 321.5, 43.5, 214.5, 201.5, 321.5, 231.5, 320.5, 341.5, 
  295.5, 28.5, 241.5, 126.5, 185.5, 172.5, 214.5, 248.5, 293.5, 
  356.5, 268.5, 233.5, 267.5, 372.5, 240.5, 218.5, 240.5, 202.5, 
  213.5, 372.5, 195.5, 32.5, 185.5, 354.5, 211.5, 376.5, 185.5, 
  10.5, 185.5, 43.5, 156.5, 151.5, 22.5, 183.5, 23.5, 200.5, 49.5, 
  392.5, 185.5, 372.5, 174.5, 172.5, 157.5, 357.5, 159.5, 372.5, 
  130.5, 202.5, 156.5, 231.5, 50.5, 27.5, 130.5, 118.5, 25.5, 218.5,
  129.5, 75.5, 49.5, 357.5, 102.5, 234.5, 102.5, 248.5, 76.5, 
  341.5, 75.5, 319.5, 46.5, 284.5, 23.5, 116.5, 343.5, 63.5, 185.5, 
  95.5, 186.5, 154.5, 185.5}, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a work-around (at best), as it appears to give what was expected that `MorphologicalGraph` would give.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2xUi.png"]
```

giving

[image: image01]

Then we proceed to do

```
ColorNegate@Thinning[SkeletonTransform[img]]
```

which yields

[image: image02]

Edit: some partial progress -I think- can be made as follows, if the use of the `MorphologicalGraph` command is key here:

```
MorphologicalGraph@
 MorphologicalBinarize@
 MorphologicalPerimeter@ColorNegate@Thinning@SkeletonTransform@img
```

returning

[image: image03]